# Create comment on pull request

Tags: github, github-api

[GitHub's comment API](http://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/comments/) seems to allow you to create comments on a pull request, but only if you supply a specific line number in the diff to comment on.  Is there a way to create a comment on the pull request as a whole, the equivalent of typing at the bottom of the pull request screen in GitHub's web interface?

Comment: I was unable to use an OAuth2 token sent in a header to make the comment, but was able to successfully do so using `-u "<user_name>"` in the POST request.

Comment: In GitHub workflows, there is the action "comment on PR": https://github.com/unsplash/comment-on-pr

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The [section of the API docs you are referencing](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#create-a-review-comment-for-a-pull-request) relates to line comments (comments on specific lines of the commits in the pull req), and the docs say:

> Pull Request Review Comments are comments on a portion of the unified diff. These are separate from Commit Comments (which are applied directly to a commit, outside of the Pull Request view), and Issue Comments (which do not reference a portion of the unified diff).

What you need are those Issue comments, which are explained at the top of [this page](http://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/):

> The Pull Request API allows you to list, view, edit, create, and even merge pull requests. Comments on pull requests can be managed via the Issue Comments API.

So, in order to create a Pull Request comment, you actually need to create an Issue comment (since a pull request creates an issue to manage it). The [page for Issue comments](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/comments/) confirms this:

> The Issue Comments API supports listing, viewing, editing, and creating comments on issues and pull requests.

So, the [request you need to make](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/comments/#create-a-comment) is:

```
POST /repos/:owner/:repo/issues/:number/comments
```

How do you know which issue comment URL to POST to? Well, if you look at the [response for getting a single pull request](http://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#get-a-single-pull-request), you will see that it contains an attribute called `_links`, and that this attribute has a nested `comments` attribute. This is the URL which you should use for reading and creating pull request comments, the same one as to be used in the POST request above.

Comment: Oh!  I didn't know pull requests were a flavor of issues.  I think this will work brilliantly.  Thanks!

Comment: One note that might be helpful to others...  Applications can't comment on issues.  Users have to comment on issues.  So you can't use your client-id and client-secret to authenticate when trying to create comments.

Comment: Hey, any idea how to do it for if comment is having multiple lines?

Answer (score 18):

According to Ivan, I was able to do something like:

```
$ curl -s -H "Authorization: token ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
 -X POST -d '{"body": "Your Message to Comment"}' \
 "https://api.github.com/repos/${REPO_OWNER}/${REPO_NAME}/issues/${PR_NUMBER}/comments"
```

or

```
$ curl -s -u "${GITHUB_ACCOUNT} \
 -X POST -d '{"body": "Your Message to Comment"}' \
 "https://api.github.com/repos/${REPO_OWNER}/${REPO_NAME}/issues/${PR_NUMBER}/comments"
```

with password prompt

Comment: any idea on how to do it for multiple lines? Like if comments has multiple line input.

Answer (score 9):

Using [GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/), you would need to get the Pull Request id using `pullrequest` Schema and perform [`addComment`](https://developer.github.com/v4/reference/mutation/addcomment/) mutation afterwards :

```graphql
query FindPullRequestID {
  repository(owner:"bertrandmartel", name:"ustream-dl") {
    pullRequest(number:2) {
      id
    }
  }
}

mutation AddPullRequestComment {
  addComment(input:{subjectId:"MDExOlB1bGxSZXF1ZXN0MTU0NzExOTA0",body: "test comment"}) {
    commentEdge {
        node {
        createdAt
        body
      }
    }
    subject {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?variables=%7B%7D&query=query%20FindPullRequestID%20%7B%0A%20%20repository(owner%3A%22bertrandmartel%22%2C%20name%3A%22ustream-dl%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pullRequest(number%3A2)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Amutation%20AddPullRequestComment%20%7B%0A%20%20addComment(input%3A%7BsubjectId%3A%22MDExOlB1bGxSZXF1ZXN0MTU0NzExOTA0%22%2Cbody%3A%20%22test%20comment%22%7D)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20commentEdge%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%09node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20createdAt%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20body%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20subject%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20id%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 1):

Use this CURL:

```
curl -s -H "Authorization: token your_token_here" \
 -X POST -d '{"body":"Some Comments"}' \
 "https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls/{pull_number}/reviews"
```

or Python code:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'token your_token_here',
}

data = '{"body":"Some Comments"}'

response = requests.post('https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls/{pull_number}/reviews', headers=headers, data=data)

print (response.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

For the ones who get confused about the different types of comments on GitHub, please read the following explanation.

> For any Pull Request, GitHub provides three kinds of comment views: comments on the Pull Request as a whole, comments on a specific line within the Pull Request, and comments on a specific commit within the Pull Request.

The following Python script worked for me for **comments on the Pull Request as a whole**

```
import requests
        
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {token}'.format(token=<<TOKEN>>),
    'Accept' : 'application/vnd.github+json'
}
        
comment = """
    <<some_comment>>
"""
    
data = {
    'body': comment
}
    
requests.post('https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/issues/{pr_number}/comments'.format(owner=<<repo_owner>>, repo=<<repo_name>>, pr_number=<<pr_number>>), headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```

For the official page, you may check [this](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/issues/comments#create-an-issue-comment)