# Github API Auth not working with adding a comment on a pull request

Tags: rest, authentication, curl, github-api, pull-request

According to this other stackoverflow post you are supposed to use the issues API in order to add a comment to a pull request. Seems logical because I want to make a top level comment and only want to include a body of a comment.

[Create comment on pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744069/create-comment-on-pull-request)

I am using the following request with basic auth and have tried both my password and a one time token. We use github enterprise so the host is correct. The Api for comments is here.

https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/comments/#create-a-comment

My request that I am trying looks like this:

```
POST /repos/mobile/android/issues/1615/comments HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXX
Content-Type: application/json
Cookie: logged_in=no
Host: ghe.megaleo.com
Connection: close
User-Agent: Paw/2.2.5 (Macintosh; OS X/10.10.5) GCDHTTPRequest
Content-Length: 33

{"body":"Here is a test comment"}
```

I am getting a 302 response as a redirect

```
<html><body>You are being <a href="https://ghe.megaleo.com/login?return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fghe.megaleo.com%2Frepos%2Fmobile%2Fandroid%2Fissues%2F1615%2Fcomments">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

Is there another way to do auth or is there something I am doing wrong? The equivalent curl command would probably look something like this

`curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -u username:password -d '{"body": "Here is a test comment on a pull request"}' https://ghe.megaleo.com/repos/mobile/android/issues/1615/comments`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> We use github enterprise so the host is correct.

True, but the [GitHub v3 page does mention](https://developer.github.com/v3/):

> Note that **for GitHub Enterprise**, as with all other endpoints, you’ll need to pass in your GitHub Enterprise endpoint as the hostname, as well as your username and password:

```
$ curl https://hostname/api/v3/ -u username:password
                       ^^^^^^^
```

So try with `https://ghe.megaleo.com/api/v3/repos/mobile/android/pulls/1615/comments`

Answer (score 0):

A more direct answer:

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  http(s)://{hostname}/api/v3/repos/octocat/hello-world/pulls \
  -d '{"head":"head","base":"base"}'
```

For details, please refer to: https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.1/rest/reference/pulls#create-a-pull-request