# How to post a custom comment back to a Github PR from jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, github-api, multibranch-pipeline

I am basically looking at how i can post a comment to a GitHub PR using jenkins multibranch pipeline job. Everything works for me and PRs are triggered and any commit to the source branch also triggers the PR build for that branch. Also the variables are getting substituted just fine, but somehow the script fails while doing a post of the custom comment from the build. Here is my sample declarative Jenkinsfile.

```html
def PULL_REQUEST = env.CHANGE_ID
pipeline {
         agent {
          label "pod-custom"
        }
  stages {
      stage('Checkout') {
      steps {
        checkout scm
      }
    }
      stage('Test Plan') {
       steps {
    
          withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'github-api', variable: 'GITHUB_TOKEN')]) {
      
            sh "curl -s -H \"Authorization: token ${GITHUB_TOKEN}\" -X POST -d '{\"body\": \"This is my first test comment from jenkins\",\"commit_id\": \"4d0f019b93c11f1fabc8313da4c461dbdbde1fd5\",\"path\": \"Jenkinsfile\",\"position\": 4}' \"https://github.***.com/api/v3/repos/***/${env.GIT_URL.tokenize("/")[-1].tokenize(".")[0]}/pulls/${PULL_REQUEST}/comments\""
  }
   }
       }
     }

  }
```

Here is the error i see :-

```html
Running shell script
+ curl -s -H 'Authorization: token ****' -X POST -d '{"body": "This is my first test comment from jenkins","commit_id": "4d0f019b93c11f1fabc8313da4c461dbdbde1fd5","path": "Jenkinsfile","position": 4}' https://github.***.com/api/v3/repos/***/***/pulls/4/comments

{
  "message": "Validation Failed",
  "errors": [
    {
      "resource": "PullRequestReviewComment",
      "code": "invalid",
      "field": "path"
    }
  ],
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.14/v3/pulls/comments/#create-a-comment"
}
```

I am wondering what is the GitHub API looking for as far as this error is concerned. My use case is just that i need to be able to post a comment to the PR i am pulling in the build as you can see, and this comment should be a straight comment to the PR and not the issue in GitHub.

Any help/suggestions here will be greatly appreciated as always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i was able to figure this out by following the below post :-
[Create comment on pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744069/create-comment-on-pull-request). I think i wasn't quite understanding that github treats every PR as an issue while not vice-versa, and so what you could achieve by doing a POST /repos/:owner/:repo/issues/:number/comments, is exactly what i was looking here. I could test this just fine using the below :-

```html
def PULL_REQUEST = env.CHANGE_ID
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'github-api', variable: 'GITHUB_TOKEN')]) {
sh "curl -s -H \"Authorization: token ${GITHUB_TOKEN}\" -X POST -d '{\"body\": \"This is my first test comment from jenkins\"}' \"https://github.***.com/api/v3/repos/***/${env.GIT_URL.tokenize("/")[-1].tokenize(".")[0]}/issues/${PULL_REQUEST}/comments\""
}
```

This posted the comment "This is my first test comment from jenkins" just fine under the PR conversation tab, which is what i needed.