# How to post the comments on GitHub pull request page using curl.exe?

Tags: github, curl, pull-request

Are there any possibilities to post the comments on Github pull request page using curl.exe?

I have used the below as below mentioned commands, but it's not working, the comments have not posted on the pull request page. Could you suggest a solution for this?

**curl -s -H "UserName:Token" -X POST -d '{"body": "My Review comments"}' "https://api.github.com/repos/UserName/my-docs/issues/11/comments"**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create comment on pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744069/create-comment-on-pull-request)

Answer (score 0):

In your question you mention "pull request" but your in your `curl` command you are calling the Issues API....I'll try and limit my answer to what you are attempting to do with the command by making a few changes in the POST headers:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "Authorization: token $TOKEN" \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/UserName/my-docs/issues/11/comments \
  -d '{"body":"My Review comments"}'
```

If you still run into trouble, run CURL with `--verbose` or `-v` option to get more information on what may be happening.

Comment: I have tried the below-mentioned way, but still, I have faced the issue. Could you suggest resolving this issue?   

`curl -X POST -H "Authorization: token 6xxxxxxxxxxxxa" -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" https://api.github.com/repos/Exxxxxxxxxxn/my-docs/issues/11/comments -d '{"body":"My Review comments"}'`

**{
  "message": "Problems parsing JSON",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/issues#create-an-issue-comment"
}**