# Is it possible to create a line (resolvable) comment on a GitHub Pull Request

Tags: github

I'm looking to add comments to a PR via the github API or gh cli. However, I'm looking to add a comment which requires the user to make the comment as resolved or unresolved. Similarly to how you would create a comment by going to 'Files Changed' and highlighting some lines and adding a comment.

I've been searching around and it looks it doesn't seem possible. You can add review comments and regular comments with the API or cli but cannot create conversations. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is followed by [`cli/cli` issue 359](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/359) (Q1 2020), and does not seem to be implemented yet (Q2 2022), as opposed to [regular comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16744069/6309).

> PRs have a really nice way of leaving approvals, change requests, comments, and marking comments as resolved. `gh cli` does not appear to support comments on PRs.